# DataGridView auto re-sort

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I'm making a program in C# that receive `sms` and display to the user, and I'm having a problem with the sort of the data.

For example, if the user sort the table by ids, from the higher id to the lower so when a new `sms` arrives it gets on the top of the table, the new sms will get to the bottom of the table anyway.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

As you can see, the id 125 is under the 0 instead of being on the top of the table...

Is there any code or event that I should use?

There is where I want to start that event:

```
public void readSms()
{
    try
    {
        comm = AppData.getInstance().getComm();

        DecodedShortMessage[] messages = comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, "SM");
        foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
        {
            if (AppData.getInstance().mensagens.Count != 0)
            {
                Message msg = new Message(
                    AppData.getInstance().messages.Last.Value.getId() + 1,
                    ((SmsDeliverPdu)(message.Data)).OriginatingAddress,
                    message.Data.UserDataText,
                    ((SmsDeliverPdu)(message.Data)).SCTimestamp.ToDateTime(), 
                    false);
                    AppData.getInstance().setMensagem(msg);
            }
            else 
            {
                Message msg = new Message(
                   0, 
                   ((SmsDeliverPdu(message.Data)).OriginatingAddress,
                   message.Data.UserDataText,
                   ((SmsDeliverPdu)(message.Data)).SCTimestamp.ToDateTime(), 
                    false);
                AppData.getInstance().setMensagem(msg);
            }
        }

        // I need to put the event of sorting here in case any message was been added              
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Thank you once more Edper for your help!

There is when I add the message in the program:

```
public void preencherTabela(int lastIndex)
{
    LinkedList<Message> messages = AppData.getInstance().getMessagessList();  
    {
        addTable(
            messages.ElementAt(i).getId(), 
            messages.ElementAt(i).getChecked(),
            messages.ElementAt(i).getMsg(),
            messages.ElementAt(i).getNum(),
            messages.ElementAt(i).getDate());
     }
}
```

And the `AddTable` method:

```
private void addTable(int p, bool p_2, string p_3, string p_4, DateTime dateTime)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Invoke(
        new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p, p_2, p_3, p_4, dateTime); 
        }));
}
```

If you want to now also the point of it, this is a program for show Messages in a screen, for example, in a disco, the users send messages from the mobile to a number connected by a model to a PC and the messages will show on it, actually I'm testing it in a friends disco.

Thank you again for the help!

Edit: Added a bounty of 50 reputation for who can help me fix the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it work!
There is what I did:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;
ListSortDirection order;

if (dataGridView1.SortOrder.Equals(SortOrder.Ascending))
   {
       order = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
   }
else
   {
       order = ListSortDirection.Descending;
   }

dataGridView1.Sort(column, order);
```

So, I got the sorted column and I check in a if what is the order that the datagridview is sorted, then I sort again the column that used sorted for the same order...
Notice that this code is fresh so it isn't "bulletproof" I'm not checking if the values of column and the order are null or not!
If you need this code and use it, take that in mind!
It's almost like the answer of Jayesh.
Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use RowsAdded event of datagridview. Inside that method you can write code to sort the datagridview.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender,
       DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   datagridview1.Sort();
}
```

Comment: but for use that I need to know what column the user is using to sort and what is the order...
He may want the id one, or phone numbers or date... how can I know it?

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGridView is bound, you could use:

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(System.Int32);
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(System.Int32);
```

If your DataGridView is not bound, you could use SortCompare handler in sorting values, like:

```
 public Form1()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(dataGridView1_SortCompare);
   }
```

Then do this:

```
void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Index == 0)
        {
            if ( int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) > int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
            {
                e.SortResult = 1;
            }
            else if (int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()) < int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()))
            {
                e.SortResult = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                e.SortResult = 0;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how can I active that event? I will update my question with some code for you can see what I'm trying to do...
And once more, thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are using Winform just add the event handler in your Form constructor. See my updated answer.

Comment: I did it, but I guess that the event only occurres when the user click on the ID column ( the tab of the ids), right? I need that the event execute every time that a new message gets in the system otherwise It will get in the bottom of the table in step be on the beginning, like I have in the image...

Comment: where in the point of your program you add the message into your DataGridView? I mean the specific function/method where DataGridView explicitly adds the message.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing could be that if the datagrid is bound by a stored procedure within that you could add an ORDER BY clause that would sort the data however you want in the first place...

Comment: can you be more specific? for exemple, my problem is that user may want to order by date, id or phone number... or even messages but I think he will not be taking this one... how can I know what column he wants and how can I sort it?
There isn't any method in datagridview that refresh the last sort done by user?

Comment: The refresh would load the datatable from the database in the way it which it was called. Maybe by having a default sort in the beginning like ORDER BY ID would have that initiated for you